# Skill points menu not working

Tags: python

Basically, the user chose a class earlier. IN this menu, it checks, and if the user chose Wizard, then they an choose to spend up to 4 skill points.

```
if Class == ("wizard") or Class == ("Wizard"):
    print("You have four spell points. You can learn up to four level- one spells, or one level-four spell, or any combination thereof.")
    Spellpoints = 4
    FireballLvl = 0
    IceBlastLvl = 0
    TelekeniticSheildLvl = 0
    ElectricShockLvl = 0
    WindLvl = 0
    while True:
        Spellmenu = input("Press 1 to spend a point on Fireball. Press 2 to spend a point on Ice Blast. Press 3 to spend a point on Telekenitic Sheild. Press 4 to spend a point on Electric Shock. Press 5 to spend a point on Wind.") 
        if Spellpoints == 0:
            print ("You have no more spell points")
            break
        if Spellmenu == ("1"):
            Spellpoints - 1
            FireballLvl + 1
        elif Spellmenu == ("2"):
            Spellpoints - 1
            IceBlastLvl + 1
        elif Spellmenu ==("3"):
            Spellpoints - 1
            TelekeniticSheildLvl + 1
        elif Spellmenu ==("4"):
            Spellpoints - 1
            ElectricShockLvl + 1
        elif Spellmenu ==("5"):
            Spellpoints - 1
            WindLvl + 1
```

My problem is that the loop never ends. It is supposed to when there are no more spell points, but it doesn't end. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, when do you break out of the `while` loop?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Spellpoints -= 1
```

And likewise for the other variables.

`Spellpoints - 1` doesn't do anything; it just returns returns the result without modifying the variable. In order to change the variable, you have to assign the result back to it. `x -= 1` is a shorthand for `x = x - 1`, where `-=` is the *subtraction assignment operator*. Similar operators exist for other arithmetic operations.